# Em C -> Várias Passagens de Struct como Parametro

Tags: c, struct

Boas a todos!

Estou estudando sobre listas duplamente encadeadas, surgiu a necessidade de passar uma struct para dentro de outra struct, para dentro de mais outra.

Eu já consegui fazer uma, porém, ao invés de usar uma struct livro, usava apenas um int id dentro do struct nó.

O que preciso e fazer a correta passagem da struct livro, para dentro da struct no, que por sua fez esta dentro da struct lista;

﻿

Com int livro_id dentro do próprio nó; ﻿

```
typedef struct no
 {
    in livro_id;
    struct livro *livro;

  }no;
```

Agora tenho uma struct livro separada do nó:

```
typedef struct livro
{
int id;
}livro;

typedef struct no
{

    struct livro *livro;

}no;

typedef struct lista
{
  no *primeiro;

  }lista;
```

Qual o erro desse código?

obs: lembrando que é apenas um código genérico para implementação:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct livro
{
int id;


}livro;

typedef struct no
{

     struct livro *livro;

}no;

typedef struct lista
{
no *primeiro;

}lista;

void iniciarLista(lista *lista)
{
lista->primeiro = NULL;
}

void inserir(lista *lista, livro *livro)
{
no *new = (no*)malloc(sizeof(no));
new->livro = livro;
lista->primeiro = new;

 } 

 void imprime(lista *lista)
 {
 printf("%d", lista->primeiro->livro->id);

 }


 int main()
 {
  lista *lista;
  livro livro;
  livro.id= 10;

  iniciarLista(lista);
  inserir(lista, &livro);
  imprime(lista);


  }
```

Comment: Note que sua estrutura no é composta apenas de um ponteiro para uma estrutura livro. Creio que ela deveria ter dado(s) e mais um ponteiro para uma estrutura no.

Comment: Não entendi, porque a estrutura nó deveria der dados? porque mais um ponteiro para outro nó? poderia dar um exemplo? lembrando que e uma implementação generica, nesse caso não estou usando a implementação de listas encadeadas, apenas quero passar a estrutura livro, para dentro do struct no, que por sua vez esta em struct lista. Eu consiguo como eu disse, colocar um dado qualquer dentro da estrutura no e passar para lista, mas eu quero invés de passar um dado qualquer, passar outra struct mais estruturada.

Comment: Se é uma lista encadeada então cada nó possui um dado e um ponteiro para o próximo elemento da lista. Caso seja uma lista duplamente encadeada então cada nó terá um ponteiro para o próximo e outro para o anterior.

Comment: Sim eu sei, já implementei lista duplamente encadeada. Mas ao elaborar minha pergunta, se você ver o ultimo codigo, vera que e uma implementação generica, não para listas encadeada, mas para a passagem de uma struct para outra struc, que vai pra mais uma.

Comment: Minha pergunta, e aonde esta o erro, qual o porque de não printar na tela, estou fazendo a estrutura livro, para dentro de um no, que pos sua vez esta dentro de uma lista, não da erro, mas nao printa na tela, creio eu que a passagem dos ponteiros esta errada, mas nao descobri o porque